# \#\#\#\# becomes "##" in printout

Tags: hyperref

I want to refer to a url using "####" as a stand-in for the many four digit codes which could take it's place.  But this ...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}  
\url{\#\#\#\#}  
\end{document}
```

... is printing this "##". `\detokenise{####}` does the same.  Without `hyperref` it prints "####" as I want. Why? and How to fix?

Comment: Leave a space in the code: `\url{# # # #}  
`

Comment: It seems that `\url` is overly zealous and assumes two consecutive `#` come from TeX's habit of doubling those tokens in output, so it reduces `##` to `#`. If you use `########` you get `####`; or do what Gonzalo says.

Comment: odd!  when I do `\detokenize{####}` I get eight `#` in the pdf.

Comment: @A.Ellett That's an example of TeX's habit of doubling `#`'s.

Comment: @egreg I would think it should have been the other way around:  that their number gets halved instead of doubled.

Comment: @A.Ellett it gets halved when making a definition `def\foo{##}` is a single `#` so `\meaning` and `\show` and similar commands double any `#` they find `\meaning\foo` shows two `#` so if you use `meaning` as a "poor man's verb" then it's common to post-process the result to replace `##` by `#` but if you managed to get a literal `##` into the replacement that would be the wrong thing to do:-)

Answer (score 7):

Use `href` instead:

```
\href{http://####}{\texttt{\#\#\#\#}}
```

Answer (score 7):

`hyperref` is sanitizing the arguments of `\href` and `\url`. Then the category code of `#` in the string is 12 (other). Two tokens are then replaced by package `url` by one hash.

I am reluctant to change the normalization in `hyperref`, because the normalized string is also used in other contexts, e.g. the URL of `\href` or `\url` is also used in the link annotation.

However, there is no valid URL here, thus a link annotation has no target in reality. Then `\Hurl` can be used that is the saved original `\url` of package `url`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \Hurl{####}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]